# Why a LIMIT clause is placed after ORDER clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, clause

```
SELECT price FROM products LIMIT 1 ORDER BY price;
```

this  is wrong
but

```
SELECT price FROM products  ORDER BY price LIMIT 1;
```

this is okay, why?

Comment: it just the syntax. Why not `from table select table.col`

Comment: it's the syntax: but logically the system must order the results before it knows which 1 to select.  if we have set {C,A,D} and we limit 1 we get C but if we have ordered set {A,C,D} then we get A when we limit 1. so order by impacts which 1 limit picks. w/o an order by limit could be pseudo random. (how the engine organizes the data will determine the results and this pattern is likely the same on multiple runs) which is why I say i's pseduo random.

Comment: It's the syntax, you just need to follow it.  Also does it make sense to get one row, then order it.  You will most likely end up with the wrong row since you pick rows before you order them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SELECT statement has two (2) clauses: ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Per the MySQL SELECT syntax, clauses are defined in a specific sequence as shown in the following image from the [MySQL website's SELECT syntax page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

[image]

The ORDER BY clause is allowed before the LIMIT clause, but not the reverse.

Comment: Please include text & tables as text not links/images, which cannot be serached for or cut & pasted.

Answer (score 2):

It is syntax. It is for the same reason that `ORDER BY` must follow `SELECT` and `FROM`

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` must be after `ORDER` because the ordering must be done first. In your first query, you would just select the first `price` listed in your `products` table. In your second (and correct) query, the `products` table is ordered by `price` and then returns just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, because we retrieve a specific answer so "LIMIT" clause give us the final correct choice after ordering process which is made by "ORDER BY" clause